# Using both mingw and msvc under QtCreator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, qt4, mingw, qt-creator

I want to make QtCreator able to compile with mingw and msvc but i don't know how.

I found some information over the internet but didn't work for me.

I tried by installing

1. QtSDK + qtvs2008 + qt visual studio addin                         **[FAIL]**
2. QtCreator standalone + mingw + qtvs2008 + qt visual studio addin  **[FAIL]**
3. QtCreator compiled with visual studio + mingw + qtvs2008          **[FAIL]**

I don't know what else to try so i will need some help here.
Is this thing possible?

Comment: You compile either with MinGW or with VS. How can you compile with Both ?

Comment: You can set a project that can compile with both. That's what i read. I didn't figure out how to do it yet.

Comment: please also publish your configurations.

Comment: What do you need? I did exactly what the answer i accepted as the correct answer says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have vs2008 installed. When I download the latest Qt version and create project in Qt Creator it automatically adds targets for mingw and msvc. In other words, when you install Qt SDK select "custom" install and check what components you are installing. Addons for vs2008 is included in the package.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the Qt SDK. That gives you Qt Creator, the MinGW compiler, and a Qt version compiled with MinGW, and is suitable for developement with MinGW out-of-the-box. Then add a stand-alone version of Qt binaries build with MSVC, or get the sources and compile it yourself (configure.exe and nmake from a MSVC command prompt). In Creator you go to Tools->Options->Qt4 Version, and 'Add' the MSVC version by pointing the entry to the bin\qmake.exe in the MSVC version. Afterwards you should be able to switch between the MinGW and MSVC version in the Project tab. You don't need the Visual Studio AddIn.

Answer (score 0):

While installing, choose custom type of installation. Selecte libraries for needed compilers in QtSDK->Development Tools->Desktop Qt->Qt-.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**4/1/2016**

I think maybe you need this [qt online_installers](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/).
 With this way, maybe you can make qt-mingw and qt-msvc work together.

Here are the configure screenshot:

[image]